# Reordering the high-level clusters from seaborn clustermap results

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, hierarchical-clustering

Is there a way to get from `a` to `b` in the following figure with scripting? I am using `seaborn.clustermap()` to get to `a` (i.e. the order of the rows are preserved. However, columns order change only at second highest level).

I was wondering whether it is possible to use the `seaborn.matrix.ClusterGrid` that is returned by `seaborn.clustermap()`, modify it and plot the modified results. 
 [image]
  b
**P.S.** The reason I am asking this is that the order has a meaning (first comes blue, next green, and finally red).

**Update:**
Here is a small data set to generate the situation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.1, 0.9, 1.9, 2, 2.1, 2.8, 3, 3.1], 
                   [1.8, 2, 2.1, 0.7, 1, 1.1, 2.7, 3, 3.3]],
              columns = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 
                         'l3', 'l2', 'l1', 
                         'b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
              index = ['p1', 'p2'])

cg = sns.clustermap(df); ## returns a ClusterGrid
```

The output is this:

[image]

We can think of columns starting with `b` as breakfast, `l` as lunch and `d` as dinner. Now, the order, is `breakfast -> dinner -> lunch`. I want to get to  `breakfast -> lunch -> dinner`.

Comment: Can you create a small dataset with the code to generate the clustermap?

Comment: @ScottBoston: This is a rather big data set and as it is visible, I have truncated the rows. I am afraid that with a smaller number of rows I can not reproduce the separation that is shown at the moment. But I will do my best. I will update the question as soon as I have managed to create one.

Comment: @ScottBoston I now added some data. Hopefully, it is helpful.

Comment: do you want to keep the order `b1,b2,b3,l1,l2,l3,d1,d2,d3` or merely the general order `b,l,d` and each subclass in there is to be ordered by the algorithm?

Comment: @DizietAsahi I would like the latter i.e. "merely the general order b,l,d and each subclass in there is to be ordered by the algorithm"

Comment: @Dataman Yes, this small set of data is helpful.  However, I am not able to determine a way to achieve your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem. It works but it might not be as elegant as one would hope for!

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram

# set the desired order of groups eg: breakfast, lunch, dinner
groups = ['b', 'l', 'd'] 

# reorder indexes/indices besed on the desired order
new_order = []
for group in groups:
    indexes = cg.data2d.columns.str.startswith(group)
    indexes_locs = np.where(indexes)[0].tolist()
    new_order += indexes_locs
    
## reorder df based on the new order
ordered_df = cg.data2d.iloc[:, new_order]

## Run clustermap on the reordered dataframe by disabling 
## the clustering for both rows and columns
ocg = sns.clustermap(ordered_df, 
                     row_cluster=False, 
                     col_cluster=False,
                    );

## draw dendrogram x-axis
axx = ocg.ax_col_dendrogram.axes
axx.clear()

with plt.rc_context({'lines.linewidth': 0.5}):
    
    link = cg.dendrogram_col.linkage ## extract the linkage information

    ## manualy inspect the linkage and determine the new desired order
    link[[4, 2]] = link[[2, 4]]  ## swaping the two groups of higher hierarchy
    
    ## draw the the dendrogram on the x-axis
    dendrogram(link, 
           color_threshold=0, 
           ax=axx,
           truncate_mode='lastp',
           orientation='top',
           link_color_func=lambda x: 'k'
          );

axx.set_yticklabels(['']*len(axx.get_yticklabels()))
axx.tick_params(color='w')
    
## draw dendrogram y-axis (no chage here)
axy = ocg.ax_row_dendrogram.axes
axy.clear()

with plt.rc_context({'lines.linewidth': 0.5}):
    
    ## draw the the dendrogram on the y-axis
    dendrogram(cg.dendrogram_row.linkage, 
           color_threshold=0, 
           ax=axy,
           truncate_mode='lastp',
           orientation='left',
           link_color_func=lambda x: 'k',
          );

axy.set_xticklabels(['']*len(axy.get_yticklabels()))
axy.tick_params(color='w')
# axy.invert_yaxis() # we might need to invert y-axis
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be simpler and more elegant. The trick is to understand what is saved in the link. The key is that, if you have 9 samples, and you merge 0 & 1, then you gain a new "sample"/"group" 10. If you then merge 2 and 10, then you gain a new "sample"/"group" 11. You just need to find the group id and sway its position during merging.

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram

link = linkage(df.T)
link
_ = dendrogram(link)

array([[ 4.        ,  5.        ,  0.14142136,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.2236068 ,  2.        ],
       [ 2.        , 10.        ,  0.2236068 ,  3.        ],
       [ 7.        ,  8.        ,  0.31622777,  2.        ],
       [ 3.        ,  9.        ,  0.31622777,  3.        ],
       [ 6.        , 12.        ,  0.36055513,  3.        ],
       [11.        , 13.        ,  1.28062485,  6.        ],
       [14.        , 15.        ,  1.74642492,  9.        ]])
```

[image]

```
    link[6][[0, 1]] = link[6][[1, 0]]
    link[7][[0, 1]] = link[7][[1, 0]]
    _ = dendrogram(link)
```

[image]

```
    cg = sns.clustermap(df, col_linkage=link)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time! :) The output figure in your solution is still `lunch -> dinner -> breakfast`! The desired output was: `breakfast -> lunch -> dinner`. Is something missing here?

Comment: The original output is breakfast->dinner->lunch, and this version is lunch->dinner->breakfast. I think this is what you want. If you want breakfast->lunch->dinner, just delete "link[7][[0, 1]] = link[7][[1, 0]]".